# Vue: Search filter on data table

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a list of data table, and I want to search on Customer' name. The Customer's name are get form customers table(relationship). I'm try more time on my code, but It's not process. And sorry because I'm new on Vue js.

[image]

Text Field

```html
<div>
  <v-text-field
    label="Search Customer"
    solo 
    outlined
    dense
    v-model="search"
  ></v-text-field>
</div>
```

Script

```html
<script>
  export default {

 created() {
  this.fetchSearch();
 },

 watch: {
  search: {
   handler() {
    this.fetchSearch()
   }
  },
  deep: true,
 },

 data() {
  return {
   items: [],
   search: '',
  }
 },

 methods: {
  fetchSearch(){
   this.$axios.$get(`/api/return-sale?search=${this.search}`)
   .then(res =>{
    this.items = res.returnsale.data;
    console.log(res);
   })
   .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err.response);
   })
  },
 }
}

</script>
```

Comment: are you using any ui framework like bootstrap-vue/vuetify or specific component for data table?

Comment: @ George Alvis Yes, sir on bootstrap-vue/vuetify .

Comment: what is the table display on that view ?

Comment: @GeorgeAlvis it's display on returnsales table that have relationship with customers table. and I want to search customer's name on returnsale.

Comment: so are you even getting any results from api? this is a bit unclear of which part is "not working"? Please clarify which part of the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: @AJT82 On the fetchSearch of method, but it work on #Khairul Habib way. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function through watch property for this.items and filter the data

```
watch: {
  search() {
    const data = this.items
    if (this.search.length > 0) { 
      if (data.filter(item => item.custormerName === this.search)) { 
        this.items = data.filter(item => item.custormerName === this.search);
      } else {
        this.search = '';
        this.fetchSearch();
      }
    } else {
      this.fetchSearch();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need a way to filter your table in your frontend.
One way you can try to do it is to have a computed variable which returns the filtered list.

```
computed: {
 tableItems () {
   if (!this.search) {
    return this.items;
   }

   return this.items.filter(item => item.custormer.indexOf(this.search) > -1)
 }
}
```

You can also look into [filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) if you are going to be using this search functionality in different places

Comment: I try on yours, but it's not work and don't show any error.

Comment: can you show us the code of how you're you're showing the table?